# Facebook Mobile App identify installed user

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook App where it can be installed on a users page and then their clients can make bookings with them. As such, the app needs to know who installed the app on their Page, not so much who is currently using it.

I can do this on the web app using signed_request and Page Id. Signed request is not available on Mobile Facebook apps though. Is there any other way of identifying the installed user?

Answer (score 1):

No, in order to get the user's information you'll need them to [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) to the app and give you permission to see their data; the workaround you're using elsewhere with the `signed_request` doesn't apply, because that's specific to page tab apps, and only gives you the 'like' status, not the user ID

Comment: Yes, i fear there is nothing i can do. Remembering I don't want the person who is using the app, I want the id of the person who has installed the app, they will be different people.